# Permission denied on pg_catalog function while importing DB in cloudsql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have exported multiple DBs from the gcp cloudsql instance (postgre 14) to gcp bucket using the gcloud sql export command, but when I try to import those DBs (after deleting the original DB and recreating them with same name) using gcloud sql import command, the import operation gives the following error:

"Error:exit status 3 stdout(capped at 100k bytes): SET SET SET SET SET set_config----------(1 row) SET SET SET SET REVOKE REVOKE GRANT GRANT stderr: ERROR: permission denied for function pg_replication_origin_advance"

I also tried the import using the "postgres" user in the --user argument of sql import command but ended up with the same error.

It is giving this error when trying to execute the "GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin_advance(text, pg_lsn) to cloudsqlsuperuser" in sql dump file created by gcloud sql export.

Comment: I got the same issue when I try to restore the pg dump to a local instance of postgres 14. Have you managed to make any progress on this?

Comment: Hello, since we upgraded to PgSQL 14  we are running against the same issue.
Did someone find any workarounds?